# Find text and add to TOC

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have two columns in excel with report location and title for multiple reports which I load into a array in VBA code, next I loop through these files and insert them into a word document,  next I want to find each of the title with the word file, change the style to heading 1 so its add to the TOC( is there way to add to TOC without changing style?). Following is the code, it does not work as I expected.

```
For i = 1 To numfiles
      wd.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=ArTOC(i, 3)
       wd.Selection.Style = ("Heading 1")
       wd.Selection.TypeParagraph
Next
```

I would greatly appreciate any pointers on how to get this working.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear how your current code is (not) working and what you expect. You need to provide more detailed information / examples. To answer your only *stated* question: you can designate content for the TOC by inserting TC fields and/or applying level formatting to a paragraph (which can be done without applyig a style).